# How does rspec work with Rails 3 for integration tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, integration-testing, ruby-on-rails-3, webrat

What I'm trying to ahieve is to do **integration tests with webrat in rails3** like Yehuda does with test-unit in http://pivotallabs.com/talks/76-extending-rails-3 minute 34.

an example:

```
describe SomeApp
  it "should show the index page"
    visit "/"
    body.should =~ /hello world/
  end
end
```

Does someone knows a way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using rspec-rails: http://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails

That is the repository (install instructions in the Readme) for the new RSpec 2.0 which will work with Rails 3.

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to try it asap :)

Answer (score 3):

[thoughtbot](http://www.thoughtbot.com) just published a blog post on this.

> Stability can become an issue as web applications evolve and grow — integration tests provide a great way to perform end-to-end tests that validate the application is performing as expected.

— [*RSpec integration tests with Capybara for end-to-end testing*](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/33771089985/rspec-integration-tests-with-capybara)

Answer (score 2):

Support for Rails 3 is coming in rSpec 2, apparently.

Answer (score 1):

ceck this link now it is very simple tu use rspec with **rails3**
http://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails and you don't need to run **script/generate rspec_scaffold** like in rails 2.x.x, now you just run **rails g scaffold** and it will generate the rspec files